# How to create a fully AJAX based jQuery-dataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

the default behaviour of dataTable is good, as long as the number of rows are not 907234. I would like to use Ajax oriented working, so get 10 records per pages, etc. I know I can set AJAX source, but only once, and then paging would be futule. (how would it work, if datatable doesnt know the number of records?) not to mention the searching. So how to start?

Comment: I'll try to give you a working link online.

Answer (score 2):

The server side approach of Datatable is like so:

```
$('#dataTable').dataTable({
  "sServerMethod": "GET",
  "bProcessing": true,
  "bServerSide": true,
  "sAjaxSource": "data.php",
  "aoColumns": [null, null, null, { "bSortable": false }],
  "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
  "oLanguage": {"sZeroRecords": "No Members found", "sEmptyTable": "No members to display"},
});
```

The backend i.e data.php should be like so:

```
<?php
            $start  = $_GET['iDisplayStart'];
            $length = $_GET['iDisplayLength'];
            $sSearch = $_GET['sSearch'];
            $col = $_GET['iSortCol_0'];
            $arr = array(1 => 'oe.org_given_id', 2 => 'usr.name');
            $sort_by = $arr[$col];
            $sort_type = $_REQUEST['sSortDir_0'];

            $query = "SELECT usr.id,usr.name,oe.org_given_id FROM users usr JOIN organization_employees oe on usr.id=oe.employee_id WHERE oe.organization_id=".$organization_id." AND (usr.name LIKE '%".$sSearch."%' OR oe.org_given_id LIKE '%".$sSearch."%') ORDER BY ".$sort_by." ".$sort_type." LIMIT ".$start.", ".$length;
            $db=new DB();
            $resultSet=$db->SelectRead($query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSet))
            {
              $data[] = $row;
            }
            $counterQuery = "SELECT COUNT(usr.id) as total FROM users usr JOIN organization_employees oe on usr.id=oe.employee_id WHERE oe.organization_id=".$organization_id.";";
            $countSet = $db->SelectRead($counterQuery);
            $iTotal=0;
            while($counterRow =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($countSet))
            {
              $iTotal = $counterRow['total'];
            }
            $rec = array(
              'iTotalRecords' => $iTotal,
              'iTotalDisplayRecords' => $iTotal,
              'aaData' => array()
            );
            $k=0;
            if (isset($data) && is_array($data))
            {
              foreach ($data as $item)
              {
                $rec['aaData'][$k] = array(
                                      0 => $k,
                                      1 => $item['org_given_id'],
                                      2 => $item['name'],
                                      3 => "Delete"
                                    );
                $k++;
              }
            }
            header("Content-type:application/json");
            echo json_encode($rec);
?>
```

The parameters like:
`iDisplayStart` and `iDisplayLength` etc are default given by Datatables.

Some online working examples are:

https://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/
http://phpflow.com/php/datatables-example-server-side-processing-with-php/
http://phpflow.com/demo/datatable/

A github repository of my code is below with some additional features offcourse:

https://github.com/shaktiphartiyal/DataTable-Editor-Free